# take input from barcode scanner without cursor display for an application in python

Tags: python, barcode

I was trying to run a python program which takes the barcode reader's input and pass to my program to check the database.
I was checking this with a sample program to takes input and print the input. But when it print , it prints the input value on the screen where the cursor is placed as well as in the output.
my sample which I have used to check the input is

I was checking this with a sample program to takes input and print the input. But when it print , it prints the input value on the screen where the cursor is placed as well as in the output.
my sample which I have used to check the input is

```
    
    import keyboard

    barcode_data = ''




    def on_key_press(event):
        global barcode_data
        key = event.name

    # Check if the key is a letter, number, or dash (common barcode characters)
       if len(key) == 1 and (key.isalnum() or key == '-'):
           barcode_data += key
       elif key == 'enter':
           print('Barcode scanned:', barcode_data
                                  )
        barcode_data = ''


       keyboard.on_press(on_key_press)

    # Keep the program running
    while True:
    pass
```

what do I need to update to stop this issue